# Tranlsation of english to nested quantifiers and forming their negations

Tags: logic

You are given the following propositional function:
B(x,y): Writer x has written a book on subject y.

The domain for x is all people in the world, and the domain for y is all subjects in the
world. Now translate the following English sentences to quantified propositions. Clearly
state any assumption you have to make in the process. You can introduce any number of
additional propositional functions you feel is necessary. Finally, describe the minimum
evidence needed to show that the sentence is false. In case of multiple such evidences,
mention all.
(a) All writers have written a book on some subject.
(b) Some writers have written books on all subjects.
(c) No writer has written books on all subjects.
(d) Some writer has not written on any subject.

(a) ∀x∃yB(x,y)
(b) ∃x∀yB(x,y)
(c) ¬∀x∀yB(x,y)
(d) ∃x∀y¬B(x,y)

'Clearly state any assumption you have to make in the process. You can introduce any number of additional propositional functions you feel is necessary.' - I don't any necessity for either of these. Clearly, I must be missing something.

The minimum evidence needed to show that the sentence is false:
(a) Some writer has not written a book on any subject.
(b) Every writer has not written a book on some subject.
(c) Every writer has written a book on every subject.
(d) Every writer has written a book on some subject.

'In case of multiple such evidences, mention all.' - Again, don't see any need for this. Clearly, something is amiss in my solution??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing anything about introducing other functions. You don't need any, as your answers show.  Your answer to c is not correct.  You have said it is not the case that (all writers have written on all subjects).   I would express the evidence that b is wrong as "there is some subject that no writer has written on".  I read your version to say b is false if for each writer there is some subject that s/he has not written on.  Your evidence that c is false needs to be updated once you fix your c.  The line about multiple evidences would apply if you needed to find two disjoint events to disprove some assertion, but again I don't see the need.